# Excluding node_modules from Webpack 4 bundle for web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

What I want to do:

Exclude my node_modules from being bundled by Webpack 4 (not just the babel-loader).

My current production bundle size:

```
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 34941ms
Built at: 09/23/2020 2:05:13 PM
             Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
./public/bundle.js  4.87 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  bundle
Entrypoint bundle [big] = ./public/bundle.js
```

My current development bundle size:

```
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 10780ms
Built at: 09/23/2020 1:50:15 PM
                 Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
    ./public/bundle.js  10.4 MiB  bundle  [emitted]        bundle
./public/bundle.js.map  11.2 MiB  bundle  [emitted] [dev]  bundle
Entrypoint bundle = ./public/bundle.js ./public/bundle.js.map
```

To my knowledge, 4.87 MiB and 10.4 MiB are MASSIVE for a webpack bundle.

My current production webpack config:

```
'use strict'
const SpeedMeasurePlugin = require('speed-measure-webpack-plugin')
const smp = new SpeedMeasurePlugin()
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = smp.wrap({

  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    'bundle': './client/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      include: /\.js$/,
    })],
    minimize: true
  },
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'env']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

What I have tried:

- Using webpack-node-externals

```
target: 'node', // I've also tried target: 'web' as well.
externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
```

This successfully excludes node_modules, BUT causes a breaking error in my app:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.react (external "react":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../client/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

I've read into this and it seems that this webpack-node-externals package should not be used for web applications. Removing the externals prop, and toggling target between 'node' and 'web' does not exclude my node_modules successfully.

Am I doomed here? Do I simply have a huge application and should not expect to get the bundle size down any further from 4.87 MiB for production and 10.4 MiB for development? It seems extremely large based on everything I've read.